# JQuery Autocomplete drop down layout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I am implementing a JQuery autocomplete on a HTML page. Unfortunately, the drop down layout is not a clean box with entries (see http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but rather a ul-like list of links:

[image]

I am using:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js'
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The CSS file is quite important. http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: include jqueryUI css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the jquery ui CSS file that gives the style to your page.

Add the following line to your HTML page  tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```